# Using Spring managed DAO without controller?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to get my Portlets work with some DAO Objects which I configured as spring beans. I've included an application.xml to my WEB-INF, added it to my web.xml, configured hibernater support, a datasource. Everything seems fine, after deployment I see the context loaded message from spring. Now I'm trying to get one dao object injected in my regular portlet (extends GenericPortlet) with the

> [at]Autowired

Annonation. But the object is still null. Isn't it possible to use spring managed DAO objects without a regular spring mvc controller?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes that the DAO is to be injected into must be also inside ths spring context.
You can either take a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/portlet.html), or get the DAO by accessing the `ApplicationContext`, rather than have the beans injected. The ApplicationContext can be obtained with:

```
PortletApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(portletContext)
```

Comment: Well I was excepting such thing. I don't want to refactor all my portlets to spring mvc portlet. Do you have an example to get the DAO by the ApplicationContext

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow and report here - maybe it could work through the portletcontext. thanks Bozho!

Comment: PortletApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(portletContext) - this is it.